What is the correct way to do a split in powerapp
I need to split info from a text into numbers and text, and find the max value of numbers. For example in TextInput1 I have "5-6 working days", and I need to extract the number 6 who is the max number of the string. I get the following error :

Expected number; we expected a number at this point in the formula

DataLivrare: Text(
                    If(
                        IsNumeric(ThisRecord.Value.'Data livrare'),
                    
                        Today() + Value(ThisRecord.Value.'Data livrare'),

                        
                        Today() + Max(
                            ForAll(
                                Split(Substitute(ThisRecord.Value.'Data livrare', "-", " "), " "), 
                                If(
                                    IsNumeric(Value), // Check if each part of the split is numeric
                                    Value(Value),     // Convert it to a number
                                    Blank()           // Ignore non-numeric parts
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    "dd.mm.yyyy"
                ); 
//DataLivrare is DeliveryDate


Can you give some more examples of expected value and expected outcome as well.
